# Autohotkey script doesn't work when VSCode focused

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, visual-studio-code

The default behavior for the shortcut <Windows Key + Number> is to open the respective application on your taskbar. I have this behavior overridden by the AHK script posted [here](https://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip224.htm#:%7E:text=Hold%20down%20Windows%20key%20and,virtual%20desktop%20from%20the%20left.), which changes the shortcut to switch between virtual desktops instead.

This script has been working for me for a long time, but when I recently switched editors from emacs to VSCode, I have encountered the problem that whenever VSCode is focused, the shortcut reverts to the default behavior of opening the taskbar application.

If it matters, I am using VSCode through WSL, but I don't think it's relevant since the problem still occurs when I use VSCode on the Windows side.

I researched totally disabling the native shortcuts, but it doesn't seem like there is a way to disable individual Win+X shortcuts on Windows - the Windows key is either totally disabled or enabled. This problem is very annoying, because I frequently switch desktops and I keep opening Outlook instead of the desktop with my browser in it.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62090106/can-vscodevim-ignore-windows-key-combination) worked for me. I think it was a problem with VSCodeVim (not sure why I didn't consider that might be the culprit.)

I added the following to my settings.json:

`"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing in the steps you took to resolve your issue. It's Stack Overflow, but that doesn't mean the question/answer linked will always be there.